# What's the best way to find your base in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Things I've tried:

1. Compass to find my spawn point. Didn't work; my base is farther from my spawn point than you'd think
2. Maps. Also didn't help much; I was a bit careless about making them so I don't see any relationship between them and I can't figure out where they are in relation to each other
3. Building MASSIVE pillars as landmarks; I fell to my death and now I can't find them either.

Anyone got any other ideas or do I scrap this world and start fresh?

Comment: Lodestone (assuming you're playing on 1.16)

Comment: It allows for proper usage of compasses whilst in the Nether and the End. So not gonna help in the overworld, is it?

Comment: You're right, my bad. You could always use a lodestone in the nether near your nether portal. You could also build some kind of path leading from your spawn to your base.

Comment: And yet... "A lodestone is a block that can be used to alter the point where compasses lead. It can be used in all three dimensions"

Comment: Depends on how far you want to go to find it. Are you willing to use outside programs/cheats to find your base? In case not, I can't really think of a easy way to find it... Also, quick question, how much have you played/explored in this world?

Answer (score 2):

> I fell to my death and now I can't find them either.

**If you have died and don't have any items** then there is no way to find your base other than looking at the world data files, because there is nothing in the game that will point you at “a place where I built a bunch of stuff previously”.

In that case, you can go to your world spawn point and search outward from there — try to look for familiar terrain you might have traversed to get *to* your base location.

If your base has a Nether portal, then conducting a search can be easier, since distances are much shorter — but the Nether is more dangerous to traverse, and a portal might be easily hidden on the other side of some terrain if you haven't extensively built paths from it.

---

On the other hand, if you're **preparing** for getting lost while still having your items, then the best option for consistently finding your way home is a compass tied to a lodestone in your base, since it will point the correct direction no matter how far away you are.

Maps can also be useful — for more than just the area they cover, because if you're outside the map's coverage area but still somewhat in the area, a dot will be displayed on the border of the map showing which side of the map you're past. I believe the dot eventually disappears if you're far enough away, though. Remember that maps can be "zoomed out" by combining them with paper on a cartography table; this makes them show a larger area. Also, if you duplicate a map then all the copies will show the same contents even after mapping more area, so keeping a copy safe ensures your mapping work isn't lost if you die with one of the copies.

Comment: I have 2 nether portals up, but I don't know where they are in either world and both actually are pretty well hidden naturally given where they spawned in the Nether. I'm intrigued about looking at the world data files. Have you got a resource for that?

Comment: @Ortund No, sorry; I have not done it in years and do not know what the best current tools are.

Answer (score 0):

You can click F3 on your keyboard and take a screenshot of:

Block:  *Your coordinates*

After it you can teleport to it

Answer (score 0):

You said you´ve used maps but, it sounds like you have only tried normal ones. Try making a locator map (map with the arrow where your aiming) and look for where your house is, then just head that direction. Locator map recipe is 8x paper around the outside and a compass in the middle. Though it requires you to make a whole new map to fill it can be worth your while.